# Large UIImage not showing in UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm capturing a full page screenshot of a UIWebView and passing the image through a segue:

```
// WebViewController.swift
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "captureSegue" {
        var captureViewcontroller:CaptureViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! CaptureViewController
        captureViewcontroller.tempCaptureImage = image
    }
}
```

The UIImage is then being saved to `Documents/Images` in the application directory just fine. If I open it from the file system it shows just fine in Preview. However, if the screenshot is really large, the images won't show in a UIImageView. The UIImageView renders blank. Adding a breakpoint shows that the image data is there, just not rendering.

```
// CaptureViewController.swift
var tempCaptureImage: UIImage?

@IBOutlet weak var imageScrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var captureImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var titleField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    if let image = tempCaptureImage {
        captureImageView.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: image.size)
        captureImageView.image = image
        imageScrollView.contentSize = image.size

        let scrollViewFrame = imageScrollView.bounds
        let scaleWidth = scrollViewFrame.size.width / imageScrollView.contentSize.width
        let scaleHeight = scrollViewFrame.size.height / imageScrollView.contentSize.height
        let minScale = min(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
        imageScrollView.minimumZoomScale = minScale;

        imageScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1.0
        imageScrollView.zoomScale = minScale;

    }
}
```

Could this be because the image is large? If the pages that I capture are smaller, then the images show just fine. Are there any recommended techniques for viewing large images on iDevices?

**EDIT:**

Here is the output of the Variables View with a breakpoint. Maybe you see something I'm missing.

[image: Breakpoint variable view in CaptureViewController]

Comment: did you try `captureImageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill`?

Comment: @DharmeshKheni Thank you for the suggestion! It didn't seem to change anything. The strange thing is that the scrollView is getting the appropriate image height, but the UIImage subview just doesn't display unless the image is small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not give any info on how large the image actually is, so it's impossible to say what limit you might be hitting. Remember, though, that a triple-scale image multiplies the underlying bitmap memory size by 9 in comparison to a single-scale image. That's an order of magnitude! I can well believe that you would quickly exceed the memory capacity of the app and even crash if you tried to access an image that's too large. So step one would surely be to load the image as a single-scale image; see the ImageIO framework to learn how to do that. See also the docs on CATiledLayer if you want to know how to display a very large image.

Comment: I changed the `viewDidAppear` override to the below code and it worked!

Comment: Glad to see that you got somewhere with this; it is certainly right that you should not use a higher scale or size for an image than you actually need for display. I still think, though, that using ImageIO would have been better, because at no time would the overscaled bitmap be held in memory, whereas that code loads the high-scaled image as an image into memory and might crash on a device.

Comment: Ah, I see. This makes sense. I'll update to use ImageIO because it is indeed still crashing on the device even though it works in the simulator.

Comment: Is ImageIO the same as Core Image?

Comment: No, it's the same as ImageIO. :))))) https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/ImageIOGuide/imageio_basics/ikpg_basics.html

Comment: Please note, though, that some images are just too darned big. Plus it looks to me, though I can't be sure, as if you are holding the snapshot image in memory, so you might _already_ be using too much memory before you even get started dealing with it.

Comment: So I should probably save the image to the `Documents` directory and load it into imageIO with the path instead of passing it in memory through a segue? Thanks Matt. You've been very helpful!

Comment: That's what I would do: get the image and (if that doesn't crash you) get rid of it to disk immediately, which you can do with ImageIO as well, and release that memory. Then later when you need it, read it in using ImageIO, limiting the scale and size as you do.

Answer (score 3):

For people have similar problem, maybe tried to test in real device. For me, image with size 1000 x 7000 isn't displayed in Simulator nor Interface Builder, but can be displayed in an iPhone 6s plus.

Also, Interface Builder will complain if image size is larger than 10000 x 10000.